# Name of two dimensional-space --- feature-space

Tags: descriptive-statistics, terminology

I have 2 features and want to perform some functions independently on them in two-dimensions. So basically I have 2 two-dimension spaces. How can I name them? Should they be called as feature-space 1 and feature-space 2 or observation-space 1 and observation-space 2, or any other name would be better?

Comment: I think it depends on what you're trying to get at. Personally, I think names should be descriptive/informative rather than generic.

Comment: @rocinante How about if I want to compute some values through a statistical procedure on x-axis and then assign specific values on y-axis (i.e., assigning a membership).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by performing statistical procedure on the x axis. In math books, authors refer to image spaces, pre-image spaces, function spaces, etc to denote what they're doing with mappings. I don't know if this is what you're after.

Comment: By convention, a space is called by the nature of its axes. So, if your space is defined by axes features where observations as points lie in - your space is feature space.

Comment: @ttnphns would it be features space or feature spaces, as I have 2 two-dimensional spaces. Both spaces are totally independent but are within the same system. For example, space 1 takes values 10 to 50 on x-axis and 0 to 1 on y-axis, similarly, space 2 takes 85 to 100 on x-axis and 0 to 1 on y-axis.

Comment: @rocinante statistical procedure mean applying some statistical method on data which is plotted along x-axis and then assigning that plotted data membership value on y-axis.